# Netplan - add secondary IP address and assign label

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, netplan

I saw the same question here, but I can't find it anymore. How can I add secondary IP address and assign a label to it via netplan?

I have this netplan config:

```yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
      - 12.34.56.78/24
      - 98.76.54.32/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 12.34.56.1
  version: 2
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 12.34.56.78  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 12.34.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fede:7ecc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:de:7e:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1656148  bytes 121855580 (121.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5300728  bytes 7534018953 (7.5 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1342850  bytes 259593981 (259.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1342850  bytes 259593981 (259.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I managed to add secondary IP address and assign label to it via `ip addr`: `ip addr add 98.76.54.32/24 dev eth0 label eth0:1` and I got this:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 12.34.56.78  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 12.34.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fede:7ecc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:de:7e:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1656148  bytes 121855580 (121.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5300728  bytes 7534018953 (7.5 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0:1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 98.76.54.32  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 08:00:27:de:7e:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1342850  bytes 259593981 (259.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1342850  bytes 259593981 (259.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But how to do it via netplan?

Comment: Run  **netplan apply** command to apply the netsplan configuration

Comment: @ShivamAhuja excuse me? How is this going to help me? This will just reset label for IP address. I need to add label for IP address in netplan config. I perfectly know how to apply netplan configuration

Comment: Is this answer your question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216295/how-to-set-label-to-secondary-ip-address-with-netplan

Comment: On Linux the only reason to use an address with a label is to have `ifconfig` (and only this command) display fake additional interfaces because it's still using the old superseded netdevice(7) ioctl interface instead of the (already 23+-years old) rtnetlink(7) socket interface. There's no other use.. On Linux this command should always be replaced with `ip link` and/or `ip addr`, because it can't use the newer features available. The routing stack, the firewall, won't see a 2nd interface but an address. I'm telling there's no reason to have to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 12.34.56.78/24
      labels:
        eth0:0:
          addresses:
            - 98.76.54.32/24
```